# Form Validation is not validating

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

Today I wanted to practice building a form and validating it using JavaScript.
This is my code for the form:

```
<form id="practiseForm">
   <fieldset id="controls">
    <div>
      <label for="fname">First Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="fname">
    </div>
    <div>
       <label for="lname">Last Name: </label>
       <input type="text" id="lname">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="email">Email: </label>
        <input id="email" type="text" size="40">
        </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
    </fieldset>
```

In [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8AQ/)

I wish to be able to validate the complete form which means making sure that first name and last name fields are NOT empty. If they are, then I want to use an `alert` and finally I want to make sure users put a valid email address.

I finished the coding and for some reason, whenever I test the code, nothing is happening, which means the form is not validating at all. So I guess I did some sort of mistake, but not too sure what, can someone help me out?

Comment: Please add the javascript code in the question too, not just in the fiddle.  THe question should be readable as-is without relying on an external site

Comment: You need to bind the validate function to the submit of your form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had some syntax errors + your `onsubmit` inside a function for some reason (not really needed) - you should just use the following instead:

```
document.getElementById("practiseForm").onsubmit = function() {
  if(document.getElementById("fname").value.trim() === ""){
    alert("First Name Field Cannot Be Blank");
    return false;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("lname").value.trim() === ""){
    alert("Last Name Field Cannot Be Blank");
    return false;
  } 
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var emailRegEx = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
  if (!emailRegEx.test(email.value)) {
    alert("Invalid Email address");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Replace the random boolean variable with `return false;` each time, and you should also [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the values, otherwise empty inputs with spaces won't match your is-empty cases.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8AQ/4/)

Comment: If you put a valid email address but no first/last name you get the alerts but the form submits anyway.  See my answer below if you want to prevent that.

Comment: @null, if you like you can check this also up ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117854/javascript-form-validation-with-a-bit-of-elegance

Answer (score 1):

Based on @null's answer, but stopping the form being submitted even if a valid email address is present but no first/last name:

```
document.getElementById("practiseForm").onsubmit = function() {
    var allowsubmit = true;
  if(document.getElementById("fname").value.trim() === ""){
    alert("First Name Field Cannot Be Blank");
    allowsubmit = false;
  }
  if(document.getElementById("lname").value.trim() === ""){
    alert("Last Name Field Cannot Be Blank");
    allowsubmit = false;
  } 
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var emailRegEx = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
  if (!emailRegEx.test(email.value)) {
    alert("Invalid Email address");
    return false;
  }
    if(!allowsubmit){
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is no magic to a varable called "allowsubmit".  You have to check and return false (or event.PreventDefault()) in order to prevent submission.  Another solution might be to return false directly instead of setting allowsubmit=false - but then only the first error will be notified to the user.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rTz75/)