# Form Validation with a bit of elegance

Tags: javascript

Currently I have got the following code and I keep hearing that I should not use the `alert` function, it's old fashioned etc.
What else could I use instead of `alert`?

```
document.getElementById("practiseForm").onsubmit = function() {
    if(document.getElementById("fname").value.trim() === ""){
        alert("First Name Field Cannot Be Blank");
        allowsubmit = false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("lname").value.trim() === ""){
        alert("Last Name Field Cannot Be Blank");
        allowsubmit = false;
    } 
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var emailRegEx = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
    if (!emailRegEx.test(email.value)) {
        alert("Invalid Email address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8AQ/2/)

Comment: Another common technique is inline messages.  Think user registration screen - often you have to type the password twice, and it will say "Passwords don't match" next to the box when you tab out, rather than an alert.  Then it won't let you submit the form until everything is valid.

Comment: You should post this (without code) on http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I usually use tooltips for showing the errors.

Comment: You could do this without JavaScript using HTML5 validation (of course you'll need to do back-end validation afterwards at some point). e.g - http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8AQ/11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle to provide an example of inline error messages:

```
document.getElementById("practiseForm").onsubmit = function() {
  var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
  var fNameError = fName.nextElementSibling;
  var lName = document.getElementById("lname");
  var lNameError = lName.nextElementSibling;
  if(fName.value.trim() === ""){
    fNameError.innerHTML = "First Name Field Cannot Be Blank";
    allowsubmit = false;
  } else {
      fNameError.innerHTML = "";
  }
  if(document.getElementById("lname").value.trim() === ""){
    lNameError.innerHTML = "Last Name Field Cannot Be Blank";
    allowsubmit = false;
  } else {
    lNameError.innerHTML = "";  
  }
  var email = document.getElementById('email');
  var emailError = email.nextElementSibling;
  var emailRegEx = /[-\w.]+@([A-z0-9][-A-z0-9]+\.)+[A-z]{2,4}/;
  if (!emailRegEx.test(email.value)) {
    emailError.innerHTML = "Error in e-mail format";
    return false;
  } else {
    emailError.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ty8AQ/10/

Comment: @Acemi Sure. It is a relatively barebones implementation - the Javascript relies on the error message being the next HTML element after each input tag (note use of nextElementSibling). But this can get you started in expanding the functionality further.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many possiblities here, and so many examples on the web.

- A possibility is creating an '`error-div`' where you put all the error messages in. If you want you can style the div (color red etc etc)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="error-messages">
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = "Insert error message here";
document.querySelector("#ul.error-messages").appendChild(li);
```

**CSS**

```
.error-messages{color: red}
```

- Another possibility are inline error messages next to the text box
- Error messages when you hover on the input field
- ...

Comment: do you know any source/youtube video or link explaining this with an example so I can learn it?

Comment: I am trying to use your above example in my own code, but I don't have <ul> nor <il> in my html code.

Comment: thank you for your help but another user did also stuff in my code, which was also very useful.

Comment: Its just a possiblity... and you can just put the ul anywhere on your own page.